# React native navigation slide from top

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to create navigating animation whether my new screen slide from top to bottom. This code works like slide from bottom to top, I don't understand how to change it.

```
const SlideFromTop = (props: StackCardInterpolationProps): StackCardInterpolatedStyle => {
    const progress = Animated.add(
        props.current.progress.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 1],
            outputRange: [0, 1],
            extrapolate: 'clamp',
        }),
        props.next
            ? props.next.progress.interpolate({
                inputRange: [0, 1],
                outputRange: [0, 1],
                extrapolate: 'clamp',
            })
            : 0
    );
    
    return {
        cardStyle: {
            transform: [
                {
                    translateY: Animated.multiply(
                        progress.interpolate({
                            inputRange: [0, 1, 2],
                            outputRange: [
                                props.layouts.screen.height, // Focused, but offscreen in the beginning
                                0, // Fully focused
                                props.layouts.screen.height * -0.3, // Fully unfocused
                            ],
                            extrapolate: 'clamp',
                        }),
                        props.inverted
                    ),
                },
            ],
        },
    };
};
```

My navigation looks like

```
<NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName="List"
        headerMode="none">
        <Stack.Screen
            name="Calendar"
            component={CalendarSlider}
            options={{
                title: 'CalendarSlider',
                cardStyleInterpolator: SlideFromTop,
            }}
        />
    </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be with the `outputRange` of your interpolator - you probably want to specify `-props.layouts.screen.height` as the start- and endpoint, so that to position the screen top off screen:

```
outputRange: [
  -props.layouts.screen.height,
  0,
  -props.layouts.screen.height,
]
```

Comment: Thanks, this works:
       outputRange: [
                                -props.layouts.screen.width,
                                0,
                                props.layouts.screen.width
                            ],